# Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied, although the paramater is supplied and not null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, code-behind

I have the followind Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_languagageDontMatch]
(@param1 NVARCHAR(150))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM Languages
WHERE Languages.ID_language not in (SELECT editorLanguage.IDlanguage FROM editorLanguage where editorLanguage.IDuser = @param1)
END
```

And the following code:

```
string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SD_languagageDontMatch";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
SqlDataReader reader;


cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
sqlConnection1.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//do stuff

reader.Close();
sqlConnection1.Close();
sqlConnection1.Dispose();
```

Everytime I run the code I get the following error:

> Procedure or function 'SD_languagageDontMatch' expects parameter
>   '@param1', which was not supplied.

I've worked with Stored Procedues before and I never faced this before. Everything seems to be correct. I executed the Stored Procedure directly on the server and it worked well. Is there anything missing in my code?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I solved the probelm by opening the SQL connection before declaring the parameter:

```
sqlConnection1.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "SD_langDontMatch";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: A user must be logged in for the code to run otherwise the page is not loaded....

Comment: In this situation it appears likely that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` is returning null. There is no code included in your sample to verify that a user has logged in. If this is MVC, add the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the method and try again. I would also explicitly handle login verification in code.

Comment: Also take a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267078/when-executing-a-stored-procedure-what-is-the-benefit-of-using-commandtype-stor

Comment: In the Page_Init I have the following code:  

if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { Response.Redirect "/Account/Login");}

So since the page is loaded then the user is logged in....